# Ubuntu 16.04 ubuntu-make android error: a default framework for category Android was requested where there is none

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-make

I try to install Android Studio 2.0 in Ubuntu 16.04 using ubuntu-make as described in the [wiki manual](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTjlIweE_Rs).

```
fieldmarshal@fmcomp:~$ umake android
ERROR: A default framework for category Android was requested where there is none
usage: umake android [-h] {android-ndk} ...
```

Another way of input didn't help either:

```
fieldmarshal@fmcomp:~$ umake android android-studio
usage: umake android [-h] {android-ndk} ...
umake android: error: argument framework: invalid choice: 'android-studio' (choose from 'android-ndk')
```

Although other IDEs are installed normally, e.g. when I run:
`umake ide idea`, everything is okay.

But I keep getting these errors when I try to install Android Studio.

Comment: Have you updated? Maybe `umake android android-studio` was just added, and the `android-ndk` option used to be the only option

Comment: @Musher How to update so that I can use `umake android android-studio` ?

Comment: Assuming you installed it from the ppa, just use `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make` and that will update it if it already exists

Comment: @Musher I reinstalled `ubuntu-make` and rerun `umake android android-studio`. It still shows `android-ndk` as the only option.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** As Ubuntu [16.04 is not officially released yet](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule) you should use launchpad to [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) so the developers are aware of this and can track it.

Comment: I had the same problem and reported the bug. You can view it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-make/+filebug/379baad8-04c2-11e6-ba51-d485646cd9a4?

Comment: A solution can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2016/04/fixed-for-time-being-error-of-umake.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution in another askubuntu thread: [Why can't I get Android Studio from umake anymore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770779/why-cant-i-get-android-studio-from-umake-anymore)

The following, taken from above link, worked for me, even though I am using Linux Mint:

You need to have the latest Version of umake, which is 17.03 as of the time of writing. Mine was old, so I replaced it.

```
umake --version
```

Don't install umake from the standard ubuntu repositories, instead add ubuntu-desktop repository to get latest umake version. Add repository by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
```

Update software Source

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install/upgrade umake

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Now install Android Studio by

```
sudo umake android
```

Comment: +1, worked perfectly. Why is this answer downvoted?

Comment: @Kaiv Hatje While running `sudo umake android` got `ERROR: Download page changed its syntax or is not parsable (url missing)`. Any idea why? (version 17.03)