# Why can't I get Android Studio from umake anymore?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-make

I have used ubuntu-make aka `umake` to install Android Studio and setup the full Android SDK. But since I have upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Kubuntu to be precise) I am not able to install Android stack this way. Here is my console output:

```
$ umake android
ERROR: A default framework for category Android was requested where there is none
usage: umake android [-h] {android-ndk} ...
```

Apparently, there is no android-studio or android-sdk option available. Does anyone know why? Also, same goes for eclipse under ide section.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To install Android Studio in Ubuntu 16.04 ,You need the latest version of umake which is 16.05 .
Check your umake version using

```
umake --version
```

you need to not, install umake from the standard ubuntu repositories, instead add ubuntu-desktop repository to get latest umake version.
Add repository by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
```

Update software Source

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install/upgrade umake

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Now install Android Studio by

```
sudo umake android android-studio
```

Comment: I did same as mentioned here. I got ubuntu-make update of 16.05. But still I am unable to install Android Studio. Please help.

Comment: @VivekJi Is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, there was. But I opted different solution and done.

Comment: From ```sudo umake android android-studio``` I get the error ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio'```

Comment: hi @JasonHarrison , Is there anything else in error message ?

Comment: @t9toqwerty nope. I used ```sudo chmod -R og+rx  /root``` to resolve the permissions error but that doesn't seem like a great solution. For one it's give executable permissions to files, not just directories. For another it should only be necessary to change the permissions along the path, not everything under /root. I'm learning ubuntu, on OSX locally install packages go under /usr/local so /root/.local seems so very very wrong, but it might just be the way to do it.

Comment: Ah, I think I figured it out. I used ```sudo umake android android-studio```. I should not have used sudo.

Comment: why are you using `sudo umake android android-studio` and not `umake android android-studio`?  Why `sudo`?  you're installing system wide??

Comment: Looks like 17.10 Artul Aardwark doesn't require a separate PPA any  more! Yay!